# get filenames' list using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Using Spring `RestTemplate` for the first time. Is there an easy way to get the list of filenames contained in a remote directory using Spring `RestTemplate` ?

TO get a specific file (filename), I would do sth like

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
(...)
String fileUrl = "https://myrepo.com/filename.xml";
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = restTemplate.headForHeaders(fileUrl);
FileDTO fileDTO = parseHttpHeaders(httpHeaders);
```

But this time I simply would want the list of filenames contained in the directory url "https://myrepo.com/" . Which of the methods in the `RestTemplate` API woudld allow me to do so ?

Comment: if I only have the dir url, how would I get the list of files contained in it ? Just the list of filenames

Comment: I am using instead javax.net.HttpsUrlConnection

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
  ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                    dirPath, String.class);
```

Then extracted the filenames from 
      response.getBody();

Comment: I have tried with this. It is not giving list of fileNames. Please provide more information